# Tailwind classes are not loading in svelte kit after setup

Tags: tailwind-css, svelte, sveltekit

I have setup a new svelte kit app and followed the instructions https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/sveltekit here one by one.
I do have exactly this in my setup now.
However, no classes are being loaded updated.
Weirdly, I also do not get any errors.
It just follows the normal CSS from the sveltekit default installation.
Removing this doesn't help.

I read in another post that I should load tailwind as a component.
Is that the only way? Shouldn't the official setup above work?

Thanks a lot in advance! I am still very very new and apologize if any of these are very silly questions/mistakes.

Comment: The guide from tailwindcss should work. Could you post a github repo?

Comment: Which SvelteKit version are you working on?

Comment: @tbdrz I reinstalled and it worked now, I am thinking its because the original installation was about 2 weeks old (even though nothing was changed) and with the guide I installed with new sveltekit updates